# ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, importerror

I have a project which has a folder structure like so:

```
project:
    folder1:
        __init__.py
        file11.py
    folder2:
        __init__.py
        file21.py
    folder3:
        __init__.py
        file31.py
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
    ..
```

From the root of the project, I am able to import the files on same path

Example,

In **file1.py**, `from file2 import 123` and `from folder3.file31 import 456` works

In **file21.py**, `import file1` works

My issue is triggered when I do this:

Example,

In **file21.py**, `from folder3.file31 import xyz`

This is throwing an error like ImportError: No module named folder3

All my **__init__.py** files are empty and make python believe they are packages. I do not understand why this is happening. I would like to know a solution for this and also some little insights on how it works.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python v2.7

Comment: I am sure I tried some solutions from that post, with no luck.

Comment: whats happens if you try     from ..folder3.file31 import xyz

Comment: Are you trying to run the code in file21.py directly, or is the error occurring when importing into a module in the parent directory? I'd suggest reading the python docs on package structure: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Have you added your project root to python path?

Comment: @chrxr I will try relative import once more. Last i checked, it still threw that error. Will get back to you later

Answer (score 1):

Module **file31.py** is inside package **project.folder3** and not inside just **project**, nor the same package as module **file21.py**. Try using in **file21.py**:

```
from folder3.file31 import xyz
```

Instead of

```
from file31 import xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
from folder3.file31 import xyz
```